# How to install jQuery and bootstrap in rails 7 app using esbuild (without webpacker)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to create a rails app by installing bootstrap and jQuery.
First I tried to create using

```
rails new name--css bootstrap
```

But its not working. So I did it with it manually.

I tried also using esbuild but at the case of printing in console it is  not working. Here is a [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql-Ng6OeI-M) which I tried.

So question is how to install jQuery in rails 7 app without using webpacker

The issue is that now bootstrap and JavaScript are working but not jQuery.

Here is my files looks like

```
// app/assets/stylesheet/application.scss

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

```
// app/javascript/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
// require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

```
# Gemfile

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
```

After all these created a controller and add some basic bootstrap,
JavaScript and jquery codes to test is it is working or not, but both the JavaScript and bootstrap are working. jQuery is working when adding ajax.googleapi link to the HTML page. But that's not a good practice to do.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So question is how to install jQuery without using webpacker in
rails 7 app.

And also tried to install by using

```
rails new app -j esbuild --css bootstrap
yarn add jquery
```

But it still not working in my case. Do any one have the solution

Comment: This article can help you add Bootstrap to Rails 7. [How to add bootstrap in rails 7](https://rutikkpatel.medium.com/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-rails-7-b7993c40e86)

Comment: @RutikPatel the question is about esbuild. And you don't need any external "frontend" gems. Only [jsbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails) and [cssbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails). BTW Bootstrap is out-the-box in rails 7. It is more native and maintainable way to setup frontend libraries

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a clean solution, based on [this bootstrap tutorial](https://dev.to/coorasse/rails-7-bootstrap-5-and-importmaps-without-nodejs-4g8). I used the same principle to add jquery. Sprockets is used for css files, and importmaps for js. Webpacker, node, yarn, etc. are not needed.

In `Gemfile`:

```
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "bootstrap"
gem "sassc-rails"
```

In `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` (note that the file suffix should be `.scss`, not `.css`; change the suffix if needed):

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

In `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.min.js jquery_ujs.js bootstrap.min.js popper.js )
```

In `config/importmap.rb`:

```
pin "jquery", to: "jquery.min.js", preload: true
pin "jquery_ujs", to: "jquery_ujs.js", preload: true
pin "popper", to: "popper.js", preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: "bootstrap.min.js", preload: true
```

In `app/javascript/application.js`:

```
import "jquery"
import "jquery_ujs"
import "popper"
import "bootstrap"
```

Install the gems, clobber the old assets, restart the server, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Jussi, it was exactly what I was looking for, although now any changes I make in the file 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss' I have to precompile the assets again. Any idea why?

Comment: It seems that Rails 7 prefers precompiled assets to uncompiled versions, even when the precompiled ones are old. I would call it buggy behavior. Clearing the precompiled assets helped for me. Do `rails assets:clobber`, and remember NOT to precompile them anymore. BTW, I removed the recommendation to precompile the assets from my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Jussi. I am not sure as this calls for a new question in SO but I am trying to add 'gem 'jquery-validation-rails'' in my application, but don't know how exactly to go about it. I tried following the same steps above but didn't work.

The workaround I found which worked was doing this in importmap.rb

pin "jquery_validate", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js", preload: true

But this is not a good solution.

Comment: rails 7 use yarn, no needs to add bootstrap and jquery gems

Answer (score 31):

> And also tried to install by using

```
rails new app -j esbuild --css bootstrap

yarn add jquery
```

You start right! You just need some addition actions

Add to your `app/javascript/application.js` before JQuery libraries or JQuery scripts

```
import './add_jquery'
```

And create file `app/javascript/add_jquery.js`:

```
import jquery from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery
```

First line import library in local file (`add_jquery.js`)

Second and third lines make this library global

That's it

And you don't need `jquery-rails` and `bootstrap-sass` gems

Comment: As the answer shows, because of JavaScript hoisting it's important to use and import a separate file and not put the three jQuery lines directly in application.js (as I did initially), as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql-Ng6OeI-M

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, currently all other answers are using `import-maps` which has nothing to do with `esbuild`, and the worst offenders are using `gem "jquery-rails"`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. I am using the following versions of ruby and rails:

```
// Gemfile
ruby '3.1.3'
gem 'rails', '~>7.0.4'
```

I am using the following gems to add Bootstrap (which allow me to invoke standard bootstrap classes and color variables in my .scss files):

```
// Gemfile
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.1'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~>1.0.0'
```

With the following application.js configuration:

```
// javascript/application.js
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = true
import "controllers"

import 'jquery'

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
window.bootstrap = bootstrap
```

Using .scss stylesheets (including renaming application.css to application.scss) and adding the following imports to my custom.scss stylesheet that uses bootstrap standard classes and color variables:

```
// custom.scss
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

As well as adding the following lines to importmap.rb:

```
// config/importmap.rb
pin "jquery", to: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", preload: true
pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true
```

And the following line to manifest.js

```
// config/manifest.js
//= link bootstrap.min.js
```

Notice that (as far as I understand it) Rails 7 works without wepback (and without needing to use something like esbuild) thanks to the following gems, which I believe are default (but are also listed in my Gemfile):

```
// Gemfile
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.2'
gem 'importmap-rails', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.5'
gem 'stimulus-rails'
gem 'turbo-rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '~>3.1.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. What I did based on this [link](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)

In Gemfile add gem

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

In application.js add

```
import "jquery"
import "jquery_ujs"
```

In config/importmap.rb

```
pin "jquery", to: "jquery.min.js", preload: true
pin "jquery_ujs", to: "jquery_ujs.js", preload: true
```

Here is my github repo [link](https://github.com/rornyn/jqueryRails7) where I've implement basic code for jQuery

Comment: You can create a new file under like app/javascript/abc.js, and pin it in the importmap with file name, pin "abc". Then you can call using <%= javascript_import_module_tag("abc") %> anywhere in the project.